# How to file bug report about frozen emacs

Tags: debug

Here what I have

```
MacOS
Emacs started with $(which emacs) --daemon
using emacs mostly in terminal with alias emacs='emacsclient -nw'
and then emacs ~/foo.txt to edit files
```

So right now my emacs client is stuck.
The daemon is acting funny too. So I won't try to connect new emacsclients to this messed up daemon.

So I can't get back in to a working emacs session

How do you send the emacs devs useful info to help debug what happened.

Comment: My guess is that killing emacs with a signal that would cause a core dump could be helpful. `SIGSEGV` might do the trick.

Comment: In general, the Emacs team needs a way to reliable reproduce the error; or, they need a `gdb` backtrace.  An OSX crash dump/backtrace is generally not helpful to the Emacs team